# Seconds of delay before triggering segue with custom table cell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, segue

I'm having this strange issue in my app where it sometimes takes several seconds (10ish) for a custom TableViewCell to trigger a segue to another ViewController. If I click anywhere else in the app during this time, the click triggers the segue.

The problem only occurs when selecting the same cell several times. Meaning if you click the first cell, segue over to the new ViewController, exit the new ViewController and click the same cell again, the problem could occur.

I've reconstructed this issue in a small project here for any kind souls to try out.
http://www.filedropper.com/customcellsegue_2

Any ideas guys?

**Edit**

Alright here's some code for you guys who don't wanna download the app.

**Original ViewController**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

    return 100.0
}

// Number of cells in each section.
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return 2
}

// Fill UITableView...
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell
    return cell
}

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    println("Selected")
}
```

**Custom Table Cell**

class customCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet var firstLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var secondLabel: UILabel!
```

}

**New ViewController**

```
@IBAction func close(sender: AnyObject) {

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

I've simply applied a modal segue from the custom cell to the new ViewController.

Comment: post the code? I dont like downloading files from unknown sources

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant code block

Comment: Added code to the main post.